# Pumpkin Carving

Tags: seasonal

It's almost Halloween at **Farthingbottom School** and Professor Charles Flavanna is getting festive.

"Right children, put down your copies of *The Origins of Fort Monmouth* - it's time to carve some pumpkins! Have a look at my creation and follow suit. You have 30 minutes and no talking."
[image]

After a sterling effort by the class, the following pumpkins were produced:

[image]

"Hold on a minute", said the Professor, "two of you have not been paying attention."

**Question:** Which children have made a mistake and what should their pumpkins have looked like?

Comment: Two possibilities: Henry & Richard have concave polygon eyes. Paul & Susan have more teeth than eye/nose holes.

Comment: The question is not completely clear: Do the two kids have made the same mistake, or each an individual one? i.e do we search for a deviating pair or for two deviating singles?

Comment: @bmyguest All the pumpkins have been carved using the same rule as the professor's except for the two in error. They have been carved independently, though, so the question could have been presented with one pumpkin fewer and only one mistake, or I could have added extra valid and/or invalid ones.

Comment: Okay, so 2 different errors then.

Comment: I would say this question is too broad. As shown by Alconja you can already come up with two different rules that could fit.

Comment: Something to do with the text?

Comment: @IvoBeckers Not if you follow the clues!

Comment: Not relevant to any solution, but it's *super* weird to see Fort Monmouth mentioned in a puzzle here. I grew up just down the road from there.

Comment: @dpwilson Do you know what it **used** to be called?

Comment: Good ol' Camp Little Silver, of course!

Comment: @dpwilson only for a very short time. It had a different name for longer than that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The two kids are

> Richard and Susan

because

> reading from left to right, the teeth should spell your first initial using Morse code
> Where upper tooth is `.` and lower tooth is `-`.

Professor Charles' example is

> lower/upper/lower/upper = `-.-.` which is a Morse `C`
> Richard should have done upper/lower/upper =`.-.` = `R`
> Susan should have done three upper teeth - `...` = `S`

**Edit** (according to comment)

The usage of

> Morse code is actually part of the lesson, not just a festive break. The children were learning about *Fort Monmouth*, where morse code radios were developed.

Comment: Can you suggest why the children would have thought that this was related to Morse Code?

Comment: The ***Origins*** of Fort Monmouth is a more specific link to Morse code.

Comment: OK :-) I'm not really that familiar with that part of history

Comment: Oh no, I don't want to upvote this because JNF's point total is perfect for Halloween!

Comment: @Victor You can up vote now, momentum lost ;-)

Comment: Either that or we need to get twice as many people to downvote you ;) (j/k obviously, upvoted)